# Automating Sheets Protection through Apps Script with the help of a common trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 10 different spreadsheets and I want to protect and unprotect these sheets with the help of a common script
I want to protect similar ranges on all the sheets but I want to do it by running just a single script and not individual scripts on each sheet.
Suggest me a script to do this
Thank You

I know the way how we can protect multiple sub sheets within a single spreadsheet with the help of a script but I want to apply this protection on multiple spreadsheets now at the same time through a common script trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sp1 = ss.openById("YOUR_SHEET_ID");
  var sp2 = ss.openById("YOUR_SHEET_ID");
  var sheet = "Sheet1";
  var range = "A1:C5";
  sp1.getSheetByName(sheet).getRange(range).protect().setDescription("This is protected");
  sp2.getSheetByName(sheet).getRange(range).protect().setDescription("This is protected");
}
```

In my example, I wanted to protect two spreadsheets with a single script so I used `openByID()` to gain access to them. I also declared the sheet name and range I'd like to protect so that I won't need to retype the whole thing. Lastly, I used `protect()` to set the protection I wanted.

This is what I get when I run the script:

[image]

##### EDIT:

Adding this code, which is also seen in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) would remove the protected ranges. This is how I did it in my example:

```
  var protected = sp1.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protected.length; i++) {
    var protection = protected[i];
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
```

Comment: this works...can you please provide me with something to unprotect/remove protection of the particular ranges now

Comment: Also if now I want to protect different ranges on each sheet what modifications are needed?

Comment: You can either create a new variable like `var range = "D1:F5";` or manually add it like `sp2.getSheetByName(sheet).getRange("D1:F5")` when protecting the spreadsheet